# Ruby Way of Nested If Statement

Tags: ruby

Right now I have I feel like a very ugly way of setting a variable to a value depending on if it returns an empty string or not.  Below is the method in question (it uses Nokogiri, but that doesn't really matter for this question).

```
def get_let(response)
    if response.css('A').empty?
        if response.css('B').empty?
            let = ''
        end
        let = response.css('B')
    else
        let = response.css('A')
    end

    return let
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def get_let(response)
    let = response.css('A')
    let = response.css('B') if let.empty?
    let = '' if let.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite as readable as @sethcall's answer, but it should be be fairly readable if you know some Ruby idioms:

```
def get_let(response)
  responses = [response.css('A'), response.css('B')]
  responses.detect { |response| !response.empty? } || ''
end
```

`detect` returns the first result for which the block doesn't return false. This has the advantage of avoiding conditionals, if that's something you're going for. If you want to do without the `||` in the above answer, you could do this:

```
def get_let(response)
  responses = [response.css('A'), response.css('B')]
  responses.detect(-> { '' }) { |response| !response.empty? }
end
```

I don't find that second solution to be nearly as intuitive as the first solution, though. It would be terrific if you could just specify an empty string as an argument. However, the argument for `detect` and its alias, `find`, must be `nil` or something that responds to the `call` method, like a lambda or proc. There's really no reason to pass in `nil`, since that's the default value.

If you knew for sure that the response.css method would not return an array with `nil` or `false` values in it, you could try this solution:

```
def get_let(response)
  responses = [response.css('A'), response.css('B')]
  responses.detect(&:any?) || ''
end
```

See the Ruby docs to read more about [how `detect` works](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect). Here are the [docs on `any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

Comment: If you're using Rails or ActiveSupport you could shorten that to `responses.detect(&:present) || ''`

Answer (score 2):

Remove return and let:

```
def get_let(response)
    if response.css('A').empty?
        response.css('B').empty? ? '' : response.css('B')
    else
        response.css('A')
    end
end
```

Or with the use of collections:

```
def get_let(response)
    ['A', 'B'].map { |l| response.css(l) }.find { |items| !items.empty? } || ''
end
```

Avoids computing the CSS selector twice.

Comment: If both response.css('A') and response.css('B') are empty, your default argument to `find` will raise this exception: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for "":String`. `find` and its alias `detect` require an argument that 1) is `nil`, or 2) responds to `call`. See my answer for some alternative implementations to the collection approach.

Comment: nice, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, very explicit what is going on, no branching logic to keep track of while reasoning about it.

```
def get_let(response)
    return '' if response.css('A').empty? && response.css('B').empty?
    return response.css('B') if response.css('A').empty?
    return response.css('A') if response.css('B').empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `let` - just have it return the results of the if/else block...  I prefer to keep it like this as it's easier to read than ternaries...

```
def get_let(response)
  if response.css('A').empty?
    if response.css('B').empty?
      ''
    else
      response.css('B')
    end
  else
    response.css('A')
  end
end
```

Comment: The two downsides of this approach are that it has multiple returns, and the returns are implicit. If you have multiple return points from a method, I'd suggest making them explicit by using the `return` keyword. I know `return` is not typically very Rubyish, but I'd make an exception in this case because using it would clarify the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_let(response)
  case
    when !response.css('A').empty?
      response.css('A')
    when response.css('A').empty? && !response.css('B').empty?
      response.css('B')
    else
     ''
  end
end
```